# Unit testing an abstract view in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-class-based-views

Is there a way to test an abstract (class-based) view, *i.e.* one with no actual urlconf linking to it? Examples of that would be unit tests of the generic views shipped with Django itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/tests/generic_views

The testing approach appear to be not testing as if the abstract views were views but testing the contributed functionality of the abstract views as individual units.

Comment: Fixed 404 without being logged in :D